# Button image changes while scrolling on Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, swift4

I need serious help, as i'm playing audios on Tableview and managing(Play/pause/stop) it using AVPlayer. All functionalities are working fine.

But the problem is how to manage ONLY Button image in TableView while scrolling?
There are main two points that needs to be consider

- 1st is to set Button image("media-pause") on the corresponding cell where Audio is playing.
- 2nd is to set rest all Buttons image("play-button") that are definitely not playing.

  ```
  class AudiosController: UIViewController {

      //outlets
      @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

      //properties
      let  menuArray: [String] = [
                                          "Song 1",
                                          "Song 2”,
                                          "Song 3”,
                                          "Song 4”,
                                          “Song 5”,
                                          “Song 6”,
                                          "Song 7”,
                                          "Song 8”,
                                          "Song 9”,
                                          “Song 10”,
                                          “Song 11”,
                                          “Song 12”]
      let  audioUrl: [String] = ["https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3",
                          "http://transom.org/wp-content/uploads/2004/03/200206.hodgman8.mp3",
                          "https://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3",
                          "https://ia801409.us.archive.org/12/items/1HourThunderstorm/1HrThunderstorm.mp3",
                          "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3",
                          "http://transom.org/wp-content/uploads/2004/03/200206.hodgman8.mp3",
                          "https://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3",
                          "https://ia801409.us.archive.org/12/items/1HourThunderstorm/1HrThunderstorm.mp3",
                          "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3",
                          "http://transom.org/wp-content/uploads/2004/03/200206.hodgman8.mp3",
                          "https://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3",
                          "https://ia801409.us.archive.org/12/items/1HourThunderstorm/1HrThunderstorm.mp3"]
      var previous = UIButton().tag
      var player : AVPlayer?
      var previousCell:PlayerCell?
      var currentCell:PlayerCell?

      //MARK: - View Life Cycle
      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()

          //TableView Config
          tableView.dataSource = self
          tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
          tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
      }

      //MARK: - Actions
      @IBAction func play_pauseButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
          let cell = sender.superview?.superview?.superview as! PlayerCell
          currentCell = cell // current cell

          let currentIndex = sender.tag // current Button tag value

          let current = sender  // current Button

          if player?.isPlaying == true && previous == currentIndex {
              player?.pause()
              sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "play-button"), for: .normal)
              previous = currentIndex
          } else if player?.isPlaying == true {
              player?.pause()
              previousCell?.play_pauseButton.setImage( imageLiteral(resourceName: "play-button"), for: .normal)
              current.setImage(UIImage(named: "media-pause"), for: .normal)
              play(audioUrl: audioUrl[currentIndex])
              previous = currentIndex
          } else {
              current.setImage(UIImage(named: "media-pause"), for: .normal)
              play(audioUrl: audioUrl[currentIndex])
              current.isSelected = true
              previous = currentIndex
          }

          previousCell = cell
      }

      func play(audioUrl: String) {
          guard let url = URL.init(string: audioUrl) else { return }
          let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
          player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
          player?.play()
     }
  }

  //MARK: - AVPlayer
  extension AVPlayer {

      var isPlaying: Bool {
          return ((rate != 0) && (error == nil))
      }
  }

  //MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
  extension AudiosController: UITableViewDataSource {

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
          return menuArray.count
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as! PlayerCell
          cell.txtLabel.text = menuArray[indexPath.item]

          cell.play_pauseButton.tag = indexPath.row

          return cell
      }
  }
  ```

And this is PlayerCell class

```
   class PlayerCell: UITableViewCell {
        @IBOutlet weak var play_pauseButton: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var txtLabel: UILabel!
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What could be done is to reset all the images when a cell is configured. Because the `tableView` is reusing the cells, some properties are mantained as the last time they changed. If this is the problem the code could be fixed as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlayerCell", for: indexPath) as! PlayerCell
    cell.txtLabel.text = menuArray[indexPath.item]

    cell.play_pauseButton.tag = indexPath.row

    if player?.isPlaying == true && indexPath.row == previous { //Sets the "media-pause" image to the currently played cell
        cell.play_pauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "media-pause"), for: .normal)
    } else { //Every other cell that is not the playing one is reseted to the "play-button" image
        cell.play_pauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play-button"), for: .normal)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer contemplating the case when the played cell is reloaded. I hope it works!

Comment: Also, change player?.isPlaying to player?.isPlaying == true . may be it will helped some other in future :)

Comment: Again Thanks :)

Comment: Are you there @Angel?

Comment: I am here!. Tell me, what is the problem?

Comment: how to reset also Slider in same cell where Audio is playing??

Comment: I have just changed my code, to manage Audio by adding slider, all works fine... but the problem is Slider is also moving while scrolling ... Dont know how to reset it.. tried a lot but failed...

Comment: waiting for your kind help..@Angel

Comment: If you have an `UISlider` in each cell and you want a different value for each slider: you must have to save the values in an array like your `menuArray` and call `slider.setValue(slider.minimumValue, animated: true)` method inside the `cellForRow` method. But if your slider is a "singleton" only call the same method (`setValue(_:animated:)`) inside your `play_pauseButtonPressed()`. I hope this help you, but if not, try to post another question with more information, tell me, and I will try to help you again :D

Comment: can you come to Skype, wanna give you just a small demo of my problem, if you got it then will post new Question :)

Comment: i dont know, have you get my problem, let me clear it if not... the problem is, slider is also moving only in the same cell where we have set condition for Button Image. we just need to stop moving Slider in the cell... Is this possible?

Comment: I do not have Skype, and sorry, I misundertood the problem. I suggest you to post another question with the code of the slider, thus I can imagine more clearly the UI and what happens with it when scrolling. I will try to help you as mush as I can!!

Comment: ok wait i'm going to create a new Question, will notify you in next 5 to 10 min, then help me. Thanks

Comment: new question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661172/manage-slider-during-playing-audio-in-tableview-while-scrolling-swift] . Waiting for your kind help

Comment: have you checked it ? @Angel